# Creating a DIB from a buffer and blitting it to the screen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to create my own image buffer filled with red pixels and then use that with a DIB to display it on a screen DC. The result is that I'm getting a dialog full of lines, almost like what would happen if the stride was off... maybe someone here can point out my mistake. The lines in the image are difficult to see, but they alternate as a line of red, then green, then blue.. repeating until the bottom of the dialog. Much appreciated if someone can help me out on this!

```
//Filling the buffer with all red pixels
uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[IMAGEX * IMAGEY * 3];
for (int y = 0; y < IMAGEY; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < IMAGEX * 3; x += 3)
    {
        buffer[y*IMAGEX*3 + x] = 0;
        buffer[y*IMAGEX*3 + x + 1] = 0;
        buffer[y*IMAGEX*3 + x + 2] = 255;
    }
}
pCam->pTestQ->push_back(buffer);


//Displaying the buffer on a DC
BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih = {0};
bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmih.biWidth = IMAGEX;
bmih.biHeight = -IMAGEY;
bmih.biPlanes = 1;
bmih.biBitCount = 24;
bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
bmih.biClrImportant = 0;
bmih.biSizeImage = IMAGEX * IMAGEY * 3;

BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
bmi.bmiHeader = bmih;
pDC = GetDC();
mDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);

CBitmap img;
img.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, IMAGEX, IMAGEY);
CBitmap* pOldBmp = mDC.SelectObject(&img);

int iRet = SetDIBits(mDC, img, 0, IMAGEY, pCamera->pTestQ->front(), &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
pDC->BitBlt(0, 0, IMAGEX, IMAGEY, &mDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

mDC.SelectObject(pOldBmp);
ReleaseDC(pDC);
```

Resulting dc blit:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSDRX.png

Comment: If you want to work with something as a DIB *and* directly manipulate the contents, consider using a [DIB Section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494.aspx) instead. Also note that each row of a 24-bit DIB must be padded to a 32-bit boundary. For the first few times, it's easier to do a 32-bit DIB, which never needs padding.

Comment: Too simple... Thanks Jerry, converting it to 32bpp or adding an extra byte as padding seems to be the ticket.